# Estimating Area Exam Question

Tags: exponentiation, area

> Pieces of turf are 1m long by 0.5m wide. Each piece costs £3.79 .

$1 * 0.5  = 0.5\text m^2$

> a)Estimate the cost of turf required to cover these spaces.
>
> i) 9.6m by 2.4m

$10 * 2 = 20\text m^2$

$3.79 * 40 = £151.60$

> ii) 6.2m by 1.9m

$3.79 * 24 = £90.96$

> iii) 4.4m by 2.1m

$3.79 * 16 = £59.64$

But all the answers are wrong where did i go wrong?

Thank You and Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The pieces of turf have to have lengths that are multiples of $1$ metre, and widths that are multiples of $0.5$ metres, since you cannot have fractional parts of a piece of turf. So you need to round to the nearest $1$ metre for the length and $0.5$ metres for the width.

However you need to completely cover the area, so you need to round up as well.

For i), the calculation should be:

Estimated area of turf – $10 m \cdot 2.5 m = 25 m^2$

Number of pieces of turf – $\frac{10 m}{1 m} \cdot \frac{2.5 m}{0.5 m} = 50$

Cost of turf – $50 \cdot £3.79 = £189.5$

Can you do the same for parts ii) and iii)?

Comment: I agree that this is probably the way the questions are supposed to be answered, but I would think it's easy to divide a piece of turf in two.

Comment: I also agree that these questions are a bit contrived, but based on the GCSE curriculum this is clearly a question about rounding, not about actually filling a space.

Comment: Yes, estimation means round to the nearest whole number, but they ought to have used something like 0.9 to make it seem like their estimation actually does some good.

Comment: It says the answer is £160 pounds not £189.50 strangly.

Comment: I think the pound is rounded to £4 and the area is $0.5m^2$ and its 10 * 2 = $20m^2$ so £40 * 4 is £160.

Comment: I didn't know that! Well, I think you have basically answered your own question now. If you want, you may also write an answer as well.

Comment: Ok but thank you for helping me anyway c:

Answer (score 1):

What a horrible question. You're supposed to estimate that $0.5m$ side of the piece making it $1m$, so the area of the piece is $1m^2$. Everything else is right.

Comment: I also realised I need to round the pound to £4

Comment: Yes that's true

Answer (score 0):

After trying the question with knowing the answer is £160 I realised that

1 * 0.5m is $0.5m^2$ and £3.79 is rounded to £4

so

i) £4 * 40 = £160

ii) £4 * 24 = £96

and iii) £4 *16 = £64

Thank You for the time of Toby Mak and Rhys Hughes who tried to answer this confusing question as it did help me come to the right direction. c: